# How to install Go

Tags: linux, go

I want to install Go. I prepared system for support language. But sadly, I can't find Bison and libc6-dev following this command.

```
sudo apt-get install bison ed gawk gcc libc6-dev make
```

Then I still can't find the suitable Mercurial for Ubuntu 8.10, which is followed this command.

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
```

Therefore everyone please guide what I should do in order to install Go completely. My OS is Ubuntu version 8.10. Notice you can post the direct link for me to get packets/files.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't find"? Please copy corresponding `apt` output here.

Comment: Ubuntu 8 is very, very ancient — 10, 12, 14, 16 have all been released; version 10 LTS has stopped receiving updates (Ubuntu 12 LTS stops receiving support at the end of April 2017, too — see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases, which says 8.04 LTS stopped receiving updates in 2013).  You should upgrade your O/S; then you'll find it easier to get modern software installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial can typically be installed with

`sudo apt-get install mercurial`

The package is in universe, which you may not have enabled. The full guide, if you need it, is available here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mercurial

Answer (score 0):

After installing setuptools et al., the go installation instructions say that you should install mercurial with easy-install, i.e. `sudo easy_install mercurial`. Are you having trouble with `easy_install`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install go with Homebrew run the following command on the terminal:

`$ brew install golang`

To check the version of go run the following command:

`$ go version`

To see the location run:

`$ which go`

To uninstall go :

`$ sudo apt-get remove golang-go`